# atob not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to use atob for converting base64 encoded data to string. I found its working fine in Mozilla and Chrome, but it is not working in IE. Please tell me any substitue for this, or how to make this work in IE

Comment: Try this: http://code.google.com/p/stringencoders/source/browse/trunk/javascript/base64.js?r=230

Comment: Microsoft has finally added native support for `atob` and `btoa` in Internet Explorer 10.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Go to this link and include js present there:

http://code.google.com/p/stringencoders/source/browse/trunk/javascript/base64.js?r=230

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2010 Nick Galbreath
 * See full license on http://code.google.com/p/stringencoders/source/browse/#svn/trunk/javascript
 */

var base64 = {};
base64.PADCHAR = '=';
base64.ALPHA = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';

base64.makeDOMException = function() {
    // sadly in FF,Safari,Chrome you can't make a DOMException
    var e, tmp;

    try {
        return new DOMException(DOMException.INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR);
    } catch (tmp) {
        // not available, just passback a duck-typed equiv
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Error
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Error/prototype
        var ex = new Error("DOM Exception 5");

        // ex.number and ex.description is IE-specific.
        ex.code = ex.number = 5;
        ex.name = ex.description = "INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR";

        // Safari/Chrome output format
        ex.toString = function() { return 'Error: ' + ex.name + ': ' + ex.message; };
        return ex;
    }
}

base64.getbyte64 = function(s,i) {
    // This is oddly fast, except on Chrome/V8.
    //  Minimal or no improvement in performance by using a
    //   object with properties mapping chars to value (eg. 'A': 0)
    var idx = base64.ALPHA.indexOf(s.charAt(i));
    if (idx === -1) {
        throw base64.makeDOMException();
    }
    return idx;
}

base64.decode = function(s) {
    // convert to string
    s = '' + s;
    var getbyte64 = base64.getbyte64;
    var pads, i, b10;
    var imax = s.length
    if (imax === 0) {
        return s;
    }

    if (imax % 4 !== 0) {
        throw base64.makeDOMException();
    }

    pads = 0
    if (s.charAt(imax - 1) === base64.PADCHAR) {
        pads = 1;
        if (s.charAt(imax - 2) === base64.PADCHAR) {
            pads = 2;
        }
        // either way, we want to ignore this last block
        imax -= 4;
    }

    var x = [];
    for (i = 0; i < imax; i += 4) {
        b10 = (getbyte64(s,i) << 18) | (getbyte64(s,i+1) << 12) |
            (getbyte64(s,i+2) << 6) | getbyte64(s,i+3);
        x.push(String.fromCharCode(b10 >> 16, (b10 >> 8) & 0xff, b10 & 0xff));
    }

    switch (pads) {
    case 1:
        b10 = (getbyte64(s,i) << 18) | (getbyte64(s,i+1) << 12) | (getbyte64(s,i+2) << 6);
        x.push(String.fromCharCode(b10 >> 16, (b10 >> 8) & 0xff));
        break;
    case 2:
        b10 = (getbyte64(s,i) << 18) | (getbyte64(s,i+1) << 12);
        x.push(String.fromCharCode(b10 >> 16));
        break;
    }
    return x.join('');
}

base64.getbyte = function(s,i) {
    var x = s.charCodeAt(i);
    if (x > 255) {
        throw base64.makeDOMException();
    }
    return x;
}

base64.encode = function(s) {
    if (arguments.length !== 1) {
        throw new SyntaxError("Not enough arguments");
    }
    var padchar = base64.PADCHAR;
    var alpha   = base64.ALPHA;
    var getbyte = base64.getbyte;

    var i, b10;
    var x = [];

    // convert to string
    s = '' + s;

    var imax = s.length - s.length % 3;

    if (s.length === 0) {
        return s;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < imax; i += 3) {
        b10 = (getbyte(s,i) << 16) | (getbyte(s,i+1) << 8) | getbyte(s,i+2);
        x.push(alpha.charAt(b10 >> 18));
        x.push(alpha.charAt((b10 >> 12) & 0x3F));
        x.push(alpha.charAt((b10 >> 6) & 0x3f));
        x.push(alpha.charAt(b10 & 0x3f));
    }
    switch (s.length - imax) {
    case 1:
        b10 = getbyte(s,i) << 16;
        x.push(alpha.charAt(b10 >> 18) + alpha.charAt((b10 >> 12) & 0x3F) +
               padchar + padchar);
        break;
    case 2:
        b10 = (getbyte(s,i) << 16) | (getbyte(s,i+1) << 8);
        x.push(alpha.charAt(b10 >> 18) + alpha.charAt((b10 >> 12) & 0x3F) +
               alpha.charAt((b10 >> 6) & 0x3f) + padchar);
        break;
    }
    return x.join('');
}
```

Comment: how to use this js for iframe src.

Comment: This library isn't reliable in certain cases, for example, it panics for this string:
eyJhY3QiOiJpZG0sZmFjZWJvb2siLCJjb21maXJtZWQiOmZhbHNlLCJleHAiOjE0NTcwMDAwNjYsInN1YiI6ImJvbS5kLnZhbkBnbWFpbC5jb20ifQ

Comment: Recommend this library: http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/
Or use this one directly: http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/api/symbols/src/base64x-1.1.js.html

Comment: This link is no longer supported, please fix the link.

Comment: @Van The second library seems to be missing definition for b64toBA

Answer (score 7):

atob and btoa are mozilla specific functions afterwards the support was extended to webkit browser like chrome,safari so it doesn't work in IE.

So better use some other functions like :-

```
/**
*
*  Base64 encode / decode
*  http://www.webtoolkit.info/
*
**/

var Base64 = {

    // private property
    _keyStr : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",

    // public method for encoding
    encode : function (input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        input = Base64._utf8_encode(input);

        while (i < input.length) {

            chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

            enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
            enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
            enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
            enc4 = chr3 & 63;

            if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                enc3 = enc4 = 64;
            } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                enc4 = 64;
            }

            output = output +
            this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
            this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);

        }

        return output;
    },

    // public method for decoding
    decode : function (input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3;
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

        while (i < input.length) {

            enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

            if (enc3 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
            }
            if (enc4 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
            }

        }

        output = Base64._utf8_decode(output);

        return output;

    },

    // private method for UTF-8 encoding
    _utf8_encode : function (string) {
        string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
        var utftext = "";

        for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

            var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

            if (c < 128) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
            }
            else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }
            else {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }

        }

        return utftext;
    },

    // private method for UTF-8 decoding
    _utf8_decode : function (utftext) {
        var string = "";
        var i = 0;
        var c = c1 = c2 = 0;

        while ( i < utftext.length ) {

            c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);

            if (c < 128) {
                string += String.fromCharCode(c);
                i++;
            }
            else if((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
                c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
                string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
                i += 2;
            }
            else {
                c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
                c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+2);
                string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
                i += 3;
            }

        }

        return string;
    }

}
```

this will resolve your problem

Comment: This is not working if my input string has pipe (|) symbol which has to be encoded. Chrome & IE gives different encoded result for this input String with pipe.

Comment: __@Kanagavelu Sugumar__, did you resolve your issue?

Comment: @Redsandro: Use the solution by Nick Galbreath which is posted by Paritosh Singh above

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @some in the question comments, IE 10 (and above) supports `atob` and `btoa`. If you're running this within an HTA, you need to ensure the mode is set to IE=10 or IE=11. Here's a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
</head>
<body>
<script language="JScript">
  text = "Hello world!";
  encoded = window.btoa(text);
  alert(encoded);
  decoded = window.atob(encoded);
  alert(decoded);
  self.close();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```