# alternative btoa encoding in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement the same code from http://jsbin.com/ufufez/1/edit into my environment and it's not working in IE. Can someone give an alternate solutions for this to make it work in IE > 8.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524268/atob-not-working-in-ie this may help you

Comment: working fine in IE9 http://jsbin.com/ufufez/1

Comment: jsbin.com/ufufez/1 doesn't open. Can you give me another link.

Answer (score 12):

window.btoa() is not supported on <= IE9.

There are few more alternatives but I guess you can use `jQuery.base64.js` as below

```
if (window.btoa) {
    msg.dataEncoded = window.btoa(msg.data);
} else { //for <= IE9
    msg.dataEncoded = jQuery.base64.encode(msg.data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with `btoa()` (the code works fine in IE8) but with data scheme support and it [won't work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs) in IE 8:

> The data scheme is supported by Opera 7.20 and above, as well as
>   Safari and Konqueror. Internet Explorer 7 and below, however, do not
>   currently support it. Internet Explorer 8 and above only supports data
>   URIs for images in CSS, <link>, and <img>

Therefore, `<a href="data:text/xml;base64,...">download</a>` won't launch the download in IE8.

To make it work in IE8, you need to solve it on the server side (create a temporary xml file there and create a standard link to it without the data scheme).