# window.btoa() not working in IE

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to create export data to excel from the javascript below.
When testing this code in IE8, I get the following error:

> "object doesn't support this property or method"

at the line:

```
return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
```

Can you please tell me how to fix this in IE? It's working in the other browsers. Thank you very much.

```
var tableToExcel = (function () {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
        template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
        base64 = function (s) {
            return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
        }, 
        format = function (s, c) {
            return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                return c[p];
            })
        }
    return function (table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById('file')
        var ctx = {
            worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
            table: table.innerHTML
        }
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
    }
})()
```

Comment: Which IE version? What is the exact error message?

Comment: IE version 8.
error "object doesn't support this property or method"
in line return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))

Comment: window.btoa is supported from IE10 on.

Comment: perhaps the following link can help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.btoa

Comment: possible duplicate of [atob not working in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524268/atob-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: Is variable `s` defined ? Tried `File API` ?

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does not support `window.btoa`.

There are however **[polyfills](https://github.com/davidchambers/Base64.js)** out there to support older browsers.

Comment: can you please give a working example with any polyfill