# Why is IE giving me Chinese/Mandarin characters when decoding base64?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, base64, pdf.js

I am using a JAX call to a perl script that returns the base64 for a pdf but it is giving me trouble in IE. Ultimately I want to decode the base64 data and create a blob to be used for PDFJS. It works in chrome/firefox with the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/my.cgi',
    type: "POST",
    data: opts,
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
        var byteChars = atob(data);
        var byteNumbers = new Array(byteChars.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteChars.length; i++){
            byteNumbers[i] = byteChars.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: "application/pdf;base64" });
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    }
});
```

However, it never gets past  `var byteChars = atob(data)`. I was under the impression that it should work in >IE10, but I just moved on and decided to try the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524268/atob-not-working-in-ie). For some reason, it is decoding the base64 with some Chinese/Mandarin characters. Below are the results from IE11 and chrome, respectively:

[image: ie]
[image: chrome]

I've tried base64 scripts from other locations, like [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAAahUKEwin5Oyjj7jHAhWFdT4KHV5UBdE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fscotch.io%2Fquick-tips%2Fhow-to-encode-and-decode-strings-with-base64-in-javascript&ei=cAXWVafsC4Xr-QHeqJWIDQ&usg=AFQjCNEY3WwfUkZdtMQV_RvFIz7Nu26uQQ&sig2=E8ZkqCGujjlb6trPT98o6w), but the results are always the same in IE. This doesn't allow PDFJS to load the blob properly.

If anybody could shed some light, I would appreciate it. Here's my latest code that I have:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data){
        var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
        var byteChars;
        if(userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/)){
            // You can use either link I provided for this Base64.decode()
            byteChars = Base64.decode(data); 
        } else {
            byteChars = atob(data);
        }
        var byteNumbers = new Array(byteChars.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteChars.length; i++){
            byteNumbers[i] = byteChars.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: "application/pdf;base64" });
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for some reason I was having problems with the base64 libraries. So, I just used the following function to only replace atob, and it worked perfectly in IE, iOS, Firefox, Chrome, Android, and Edge.

```
var atob = function(input){
    var str = String(input).replace(/=+$/, '');
    for (
         // initialize result and counters
         var bc = 0, bs, buffer, idx = 0, output = '';
         // get next character
         buffer = str.charAt(idx++);
         // character found in table? initialize bit storage and add its ascii value;
         ~buffer && (bs = bc % 4 ? bs * 64 + buffer : buffer,
                     // and if not first of each 4 characters,
                     // convert the first 8 bits to one ascii character
                     bc++ % 4) ? output += String.fromCharCode(255 & bs >> (-2 * bc & 6)) : 0
     ) {
         // try to find character in table (0-63, not found => -1)
         buffer = chars.indexOf(buffer);
    }
    return output;
}
```